# 'Correct' style for indenting list instantiations?

Tags: apex, style

Bit of a random question, I know, but it's been bugging me for years, and every time I Google around looking for examples of how other code handles it, I come up short.

Here's what I imagine an instantiated list or set should look like, from a stylistic perspective:

```
Set<string> setEg = new Set<string> {'a',
                                     'b',
                                     'c'};
```

**Would you experienced coders consider this a 'correct' or 'good' style?**
There's a few stylistic choices represented there, but the one I'm most interested is how the instantiated values are indented.

I use MavensMate with Sublime Text, with syntax set to Java. Generally when going to a newline and hitting `tab`, the cursor will jump to a context appropriate indentation level. But for list instantiations, it just seems to provide a normal indent space, resulting in:

```
Set<string> setEg = new set<string>{'a',
 'b',
 'c'};
```

Which doesn't seem as readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the content is to be broken out over multiple lines, then completely separating the content from the container is another style:

```
List<String> listEg = new List<String>{
        'a',
        'b',
        'c'
        };
```

It is then easier to see the content or re-order it or cut and paste it. And if the variable is renamed the content doesn't have to be re-indented. This is also using a double indent to indicate that the multiple lines are a continuation of the first line.

But the important thing in a code base is that a consistent style be used so go for whatever the editor you use does easily.

Comment: +1 to this. I do not know how many times I have updated lists but forgot the first element because it was on the same line as the container....

Comment: I like the reasoning behind this style - and it appears that Sublime's formatting handles this indentation method consistently. Thank you!